# javascript : how to change the element innerHTML of a paraleling div class

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

html:
`

```
<li><div class="zb_font"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>first</div></li>
<li><div class="zb_font"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>second</div></li>
<li><div class="zb_font"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>third</div></li>
<li><div class="zb_font"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>last</div></li>
```

`

javascript:
`function myFunc(){
           var change = document.getElementsByClassName('zb_font')[3];
           change.innerHTML = '4';
}`

I am sure the function is called, but I still get "TypeError: change is undefined".

Comment: Where is your function defined and where is it called? It might be possible that the script is running before the content is rendered, which leads to change being undefined. It is also possible you're testing it in a browser that doesn't support getElementsByClassName.

Comment: IE9+ support getElementsByClassName.

Comment: why don't you use `getElementById('div1')` instead of `getElementByClassName` as @Vimal Stan says it is not supported in all browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your javascript runs after the DOM is loaded. For example:

```
document.onload = function() {

// your function.
};
```